# Maven Setup is not generating class files

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark

I have been trying to run the one of the scala-spark code in Eclipse (windows), But I could not create the class files when I try maven install. Please note the same code is running in mac eclipse. But I try to run with the same code in windows eclipse. Below is the pom file content,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mask</groupId>
<artifactId>**masked**</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>**masked**</name>
<url>**masked**</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <revision>1.0.0</revision>
    <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>
    <slf4j-version>1.7.25</slf4j-version>
    <typesafe-version>1.3.3</typesafe-version>
    <json4s-version>3.6.3</json4s-version>
    <commons-io-version>2.6</commons-io-version>
    <httpcomponents-version>4.5.8</httpcomponents-version>
    <spark-version>2.4.0</spark-version>
    <kafka-version>2.0.0</kafka-version>
    <es-version>7.3.1</es-version>
    <!-- <es-version>7.3.1</es-version> -->
    <zoo-version>3.4.13</zoo-version>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <scala-version>2.11.11</scala-version>
    <scalatest-version>3.0.5</scalatest-version>
    <scala-maven-version>3.4.6</scala-maven-version>
    <maven-compiler-version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-version>
    <maven-assembly-version>2.5.3</maven-assembly-version>
    <artifact-scala-version>2.11</artifact-scala-version>
    <deploy-root>nda-apps</deploy-root>
    <common-lib-dir>common-lib</common-lib-dir>
    <source-lib-dir>source-lib</source-lib-dir>
</properties>

<!-- Project Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
        <artifactId>config</artifactId>
        <version>${typesafe-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpcomponents-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
                <artifactId>json4s-native_2.11</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
                <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.11</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${es-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>${es-version}</version> -->
        <version>6.5.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
                <artifactId>json4s-native_2.11</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
                <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.11</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>${zoo-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}_${artifact-scala-version}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scala-maven-version}</version>
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>${scala-version}</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-assembly-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-archive</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I have setup it in JDK 1.8. Tried lot of time to remove and reconfigure setup from the begining but not working.

Comment: What kind of error messages are you getting?

Comment: There is no error at all. I could run the maven install or maven compile successfully without any issues. But it is not generating any class files in my target directory .